# Nullify column in update if subquery returns empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, sql-update, correlated-subquery

I have the following `SQL` query

```
UPDATE container  SET member_containers = members
FROM 
(
SELECT inter_container_membership.owning_container_id AS owner_cont
      ,array_to_string(array_agg(inter_container_membership.member_container_id),',') AS members
FROM inter_container_membership 
GROUP BY inter_container_membership.owning_container_id) v
WHERE container.id = owner_cont;
```

The problem is, if the `sub-query` does not return anything then `member_containers` will not be updated, I need to set to null if it's the case, I've tried using `EXISTS` clause but it didn't work.

```
UPDATE container  SET member_containers = 
     CASE WHEN EXISTS (
          SELECT * FROM inter_container_membership
          WHERE container.id  = inter_container_membership.owning_container_id
          ) THEN members
     ELSE NULL END
FROM  (
SELECT inter_container_membership.owning_container_id AS owner_cont
      ,array_to_string(array_agg(inter_container_membership.member_container_id),',') AS members
FROM inter_container_membership 
GROUP BY inter_container_membership.owning_container_id) v
WHERE container.id = owner_cont;
```

So now I am thinking of nullifying out `member_containers` before updating it, but I could not find a way for doing that.

Comment: Quick and dirty fix: replace the subquery by a `... FROM members LEFT JOIN inter_container_membersship ...` . (and *please* add relevant aliases to your column references)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the column NULL in case the subquery does not find anything, you *could* use a correlated subquery instead of the join:

```sql
UPDATE container c
SET    member_containers = (
   SELECT string_agg(member_container_id, ',')
   FROM   inter_container_membership i
   WHERE  i.owning_container_id = c.id
   GROUP  BY owning_container_id
   );
```

Often, this kind of query is wrong, because the column shouldn't be nullified if nothing is found. But you seem to want exactly that.
Also, correlated subqueries tend to be *slow*. Consider to add this left join instead (doing the same):

```sql
UPDATE container c
SET    member_containers = i.members
FROM   container c1
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT owning_container_id
        , string_agg(member_container_id, ',') AS members
   FROM   inter_container_membership 
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) i ON i.owning_container_id = c1.id
WHERE  c.id = c1.id;
```

Also using [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) instead of `array_to_string(array_agg(...))`. Requires Postgres 9.0+.

Comment: I think the second query solves the issue, but what does GROUP BY 1 mean?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi: `1` in `GROUP BY 1` is a positional reference to the *first* item in the `SELECT` list. [Details in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE:

```
WITH m AS (
  SELECT icm.owning_container_id AS owner_cont,
         array_to_string(array_agg(icm.member_container_id),',') AS members
  FROM inter_container_membership icm
  GROUP BY icm.owning_container_id)
UPDATE container SET member_containers = m.members
WHERE id = m.owner_cont;
```

Comment: This exhibits the same problem as the original: nothing happens if the CTE finds no row. The CTE is just a bit slower than the subquery.

Comment: Thats exactly the same