# Update from another table when row does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to run below query:

```sql
UPDATE tempd tvl
    SET id = case 
                when tse.id is null or tse.id = 0 then --coalesce(nullif(tse.id,0),5) 
                 5  
                else  
                    tse.event_id  end  
FROM details tse 
WHERE
    tvl.id = tse.id
AND tvl.name = tse.name
AND tvl.add =  tse.add;
```

Sample for table `tempd`:

```
name  add id
a     xx
b     yy
c     zz
d     ss
```

`details` table is blank now. So every row in `tempd` should have 5, But I am getting always 0 in id column.

Also, can we update from multiple tables? Like: if there is a match from `table1` then take that, if match from `table2` take that, else use default value.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. 1) What do you get if you do `SELECT case when tse.id is null or tse.id = 0 then coalesce(nullif(tse.id,0),5)   else  tse.event_id  end  ...`  where '...' is the rest of the query? 2) What do you mean by 'row does not exist'? That it does exist in source table or target table or both? **Add answers as update to question**.

Comment: Target table means details table, in any case ID is zero if record is not there in details table

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: sample data updated

Answer (score 1):

Rows excluded by predicates in the `WHERE` clause are **not updated at all**. That's the core problem of your query.

You want to update **all rows** of table `tempd` unconditionally. A **correlated subquery** in the assigned value does the job - with no outer `WHERE` clause:

```sql
UPDATE tempd tvl
SET    id = COALESCE((
                     SELECT tse.event_id
                     FROM   details tse 
                     WHERE  tse.id   = tvl.id
                     AND    tse.name = tvl.name
                     AND    tse.add  = tvl.add
                     AND    tse.id   <> 0  -- excludes NULL & 0
                  -- ORDER  BY ???
                  -- LIMIT  1  -- can there be > 1 match?
                     ), 5);
```

> Can we update from multiple tables? Like: if there is a match from `table1` then take that, if match from `table2` take that, else use default value.

One way:

```sql
UPDATE tempd tvl
SET    id = COALESCE(NULLIF(
                     (
                     SELECT tse.event_id
                     FROM   details tse 
                     WHERE  tse.id   = tvl.id
                     AND    tse.name = tvl.name
                     AND    tse.add  = tvl.add
                     -- AND    tse.id   <> 0
                     -- this time we need to accept 0 to exit
                     -- ORDER  BY ??? 
                     -- LIMIT  1  -- can there be > 1 match?
                     )   
                   , (
                     SELECT t2.some_id
                     FROM   tbl2 t2
                     WHERE  ...  -- your filters here

                     ), 0), 5);
```

All parentheses are required.

If there can be more than 1 match from each correlated subquery, `LIMIT 1` will fix that. But, typically, you'll want to add `ORDER BY` before each `LIMIT 1` to get a deterministic pick.

See:

- [Nullify column in update if subquery returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606022/nullify-column-in-update-if-subquery-returns-empty/22607620#22607620)
- [PostgreSQL update join vs SQL Server update join](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/291633/3684)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what the where clause is or the update you're asking for is. If you update from an empty table you will always get zero rows updated.

An even simpler example:

```
sophia=> create table empty_table(x integer);
CREATE TABLE
sophia=> create table foo(x integer);
CREATE TABLE
sophia=> insert into foo(x) values (1),(2),(3);
INSERT 0 3
sophia=> update foo set x = 5 from empty_table where true;
UPDATE 0
sophia=>
```

As to the solution - you can pick from one of the following depending on your exact use-case:

- Get the value to update from a subquery (as per Erwin's example)
- Do something so that details always has data
- Update the from so the source always has something (e.g. join with something else)